# Initialize frame object in view model throws exceptions when running unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, exception, mstest, winui-3

I have a WinUi 3 project for a welcome screen.

The following unit test function will throw exceptions, how to resolve these exception?

The welcome screen application runs properly without this problem. The frame object `ContentFrame` is created in view model to bind the frame control in view. All solutions are welcome, including those solutions that avoid putting a frame object in the view model. Thanks.

```
 [TestClass()]
 public class WelcomeScreenPageViewModelTests
 {
     [TestMethod()]
     public void WelcomeScreenPageViewModelTest()
     {
         WelcomeScreenPage welcomeScreenPage = new WelcomeScreenPage();
         WelcomeScreenPageViewModel _viewModel = new WelcomeScreenPageViewModel(welcomeScreenPage);// throw exceptions.

         Assert.AreEqual(_viewModel.IsCheckBoxVisible, false);
         Assert.AreEqual(_viewModel.IsBackButtonVisible, false);
         Assert.AreEqual(_viewModel.NextButtonText, "Next");  
         Assert.AreEqual(_viewModel.CurrentPageIndex, 0);
     }
 }
```

View model:

```
public class WelcomeScreenPageViewModel : ObservableObject
{
     private WelcomeScreenPage welcomeScreenPage;

     public WelcomeScreenPageViewModel(WelcomeScreenPage welcomeScreenPage)
     {
         this.welcomeScreenPage = welcomeScreenPage;
     }

     public Frame ContentFrame = new();  // throws exception
 }
```

View:

```
 <Frame x:Name="NavigationFrame" Content="{x:Bind ViewModel.ContentFrame,Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Exceptions:

[image]

[image]

Project source code:
https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ap_EAuwC9QkXjBxK2z-0JgrFAxaE?e=fcv96P

Comment: Testing with MSTest and WinUI3 doesn't work just like that, you must follow what's described here https://devblogs.microsoft.com/ifdef-windows/winui-desktop-unit-tests/ (Microsoft.TestPlatform.TestHost etc)

Comment: @SimonMourier Thanks.
I followed that doc, but had a build error :error CS7069: Reference to type 'DispatcherQueue' claims it is defined in 'Microsoft.WinUI', but it could not be found. How to resolve it?

Comment: I added a MSTest project into a WInUi 3 project for unit test. This is the way I used to unit-testing WPF projects. And it was working until I met this exception problem.

Comment: Yes the `UITestMethodAttribute`'s `DispatcherQueue` mentioned in the blog points to the old UWP `DispatcherQueue` (in Windows.* namespace), just update all the nuget packages of the project and it will work. Note the test project must be a WinUI3 exe for the whole test to work, you cannot use a simple MSTest app.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution to solve this problem:

Following this doc:
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/ifdef-windows/winui-desktop-unit-tests/

Here is updated test file. Change [TestMethod()] to [UITestMethod()] solve the exception problem.

```
namespace WelcomeScreen.UnitTest
{
    [TestClass()]
    public class WelcomeScreenPageViewModelTests
    {
        [UITestMethod()]
        public void WelcomeScreenPageViewModelTest()
        {
            WelcomeScreenPage welcomeScreenPage = new WelcomeScreenPage();
            WelcomeScreenPageViewModel _viewModel = new WelcomeScreenPageViewModel(welcomeScreenPage);
            Assert.AreEqual(_viewModel.IsCheckBoxVisible, false);
            Assert.AreEqual(_viewModel.IsBackButtonVisible, false);
            Assert.AreEqual(_viewModel.NextButtonText, "Next");
            // Assert.AreEqual(_viewModel.PreviousPageIndex, -1);
            Assert.AreEqual(_viewModel.CurrentPageIndex, 0);
        }
    }
}
```